# Dynamically changing height of the tableViewCell for images using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: swift

I want to dynamically change the height of the cell such that the image fills the imageView in the width and the image maintains the aspect ratio.

I am trying to do this using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Based on tutorials available online, this seemed to be a straightforward task. But in my case, the height of the cell doesn't adjust to perform this task. Either the image fills with aspect ratio leaving a lot of width space empty or fills the width but clips the part of the image vertically. I made sure there are leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints with respect to the cell view and also the `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and table.estimatedRowHeight is set in viewDidLoad. I have uploaded the project at this link. Could someone please suggest what could I be missing here?

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/Neeraj3pathi/SimpleDrawing/issues/2)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var picTableView: UITableView!

let reuseidentifier = "dynamicCellTableViewCell"
let images = [UIImage(named: "feedImage1"), UIImage(named: "feedImage2"), UIImage(named: "feedImage3")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

picTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
picTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000
}

// MARK: Table View Data Source

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DynamicCellTableViewCell

    cell.displayImageView.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}



}
```

Comment: Is it required to go with only UITableViewAutomaticDimension in your case ? i mean is it okay with any other solution ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I am trying to implement UITableViewAutomaticDimension that seems to have been designed for such applications. I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells  but can't seem to get it to work. If this doesn't work, I will try to implement other solutions that already exist on this platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured the solution. UIImageView when used with UITableViewAutomaticDimension only looks for the UIImage's true width and height as the size. So UIImageView adjusts its height to respond to UIImage's original height and not the scaled height for scaled width (aspectFit) to match layout constraint.

So trick is to first change the width and height of the image to match the width and height that you need in the cell. Rest of the job will be done by UITableViewAutomaticDimension. Below is the updated cellForRowAtIndex function that works now. Thanks all for giving your inputs.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseidentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DynamicCellTableViewCell

    let image = images[indexPath.row]!
    let newWidth = cell.displayImageView.frame.width
    let scale = newWidth/image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight))
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    cell.displayImageView.image = newImage

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need implement next method for UITableViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 1000.0;
}
```

Inside the method, you must know what dimension will have each cell. You must know in advance what height will have each cell.

For example, you could create an array of CGFloat saving the height will have each row, and when height change, you can update this position in array and execude tableView.reloadData().

```
var arrayHeight:CGFloat?
//Now fill array with height of each cell

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return arrayHeight[indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. If I have to provide the exact height of each cell myself, then what is the use of UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Answer (score 0):

**cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()**

**cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()**

add these two lines in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

And make sure that top, bottom, right, left, constraints are set in the storyboard

Comment: Thanks. I tried this as well but it doesn't help. I do have the four required constraints. Here is the project that I am using, in case you can locate any other stupid mistake I am making.  https://github.com/Neeraj3pathi/SimpleDrawing/issues/2

Comment: I make some changes in the file.I uploaded the zip file in the following linkhttps://github.com/Neeraj3pathi/SimpleDrawing/issues/2  Please check

Comment: Arvind, I downloaded your project and checked. The larger image that you have added increases the total height of that cell to that of the image. But then it aspect fits the image as per the AutoLayout constraints, leaving huge space on the top and bottom in that cell empty. You didn't face that problem?